# How to use drupal twig template available variables

Tags: theming, 8

I'm struggling to understand how twig templates work in Drupal 8. At the beginning of each templates there is a comment to show availables varialbes but I dont know where or even how I'am suppose to assign them.

Let's take views-view-fields.html.twig as an example.

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default view template to display all the fields in a row.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - view: The view in use.
 * - fields: A list of fields, each one contains:
 *   - content: The output of the field.
 *   - raw: The raw data for the field, if it exists. This is NOT output safe.
 *   - class: The safe class ID to use.
 *   - handler: The Views field handler controlling this field.
 *   - inline: Whether or not the field should be inline.
 *   - wrapper_element: An HTML element for a wrapper.
 *   - wrapper_attributes: List of attributes for wrapper element.
 *   - separator: An optional separator that may appear before a field.
 *   - label: The field's label text.
 *   - label_element: An HTML element for a label wrapper.
 *   - label_attributes: List of attributes for label wrapper.
 *   - label_suffix: Colon after the label.
 *   - element_type: An HTML element for the field content.
 *   - element_attributes: List of attributes for HTML element for field content.
 *   - has_label_colon: A boolean indicating whether to display a colon after
 *     the label.
 *   - element_type: An HTML element for the field content.
 *   - element_attributes: List of attributes for HTML element for field content.
 * - row: The raw result from the query, with all data it fetched.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_view_fields()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
```

I created a custom View which create a Block. It contains a query fetching a custom content type named "News".
Each news have a title, a body and an image. I overrided views-view-fields template to views-view-fields--MYVIEWNALME.html.twig (the overriding works just fine).

I though for each field I would have a tab in the admin where I could assign for example "wrapper_element" but unfortunately it doesn't work that way.

---

Comment: Does this help? https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/customize-the-output-style-of-a-view-field

Comment: My personal recommendation is to always use entity based rendering in views using view modes. IMHO it is way easier to provide a template for that than using the views templates. There are some exceptions of course, llike displaying fields in tables, then you have to use this.